# Role of HMM in speech recognition

Tags: speech-recognition, hmm

What exactly hidden markov model does in speech recognition process? I read it is the representation of phonemes as states? What exactly is a state? Any detail article on HMM role in speech recognition process will be helpful.

Comment: You should definitely read [this classic article](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~murphyk/Bayes/rabiner.pdf).

Comment: As @MattL. says: read that classic first. And then ask any questions here, preferably by updating your question (which may be closed as-is because it is a bit generic). Also, [this question](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/17897/using-hmm-for-speech-recognition) may be a duplicate and/or it may answer your questions.

Comment: @MattL. and Peter Thanks guys, will read it. If I still have any questions will update the topic.